# installing thrift idl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, thrift

Basically I have no idea how to create the lib files. The VS solution that come with thrift(0.9.0) say they are created with a newer version and therefore cant' be open with VS 2008. I've also tried installing or running the ./bootstrap.sh but I keep getting an error saying that the file is not an executable.I've been screwing with this for hours and can't figure it out so if someone who knows how to install thrift please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been using thrift on windows, but I hope it doesn't matter. First you have to install thrift locally (0.8.0, 0.9.0, whatever). On linux you run `./configure`, `make`, `make install`. Once you've got your thrift locally installed, you do have the thrift binary and you should make sure it is on the shell path (on linux it's `/usr/local/bin/thrift`). Then create a thrift definition file with a service, run the thrift binary against that file and thrift will generate code for you (I assume you'll generate C++ code).

Now - for each programming language thrift generates different files, of course. In scripting languages you have to include them manually. In Java you will have a package and you can use it in the rest of the code. And in C++ you'll get .h and .cpp files which you should compile into a library. **I strongly encourage you to use cmake**, which is a wonderful tool to perform such things automatically.

Anyway, I wouldn't expect that MS Visual Studio will happily cooperate with open source software such as Apache Software Foundation projects ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to finally getting it working though by building from source because the .zip release file they have available would not cooperate with VS and gave me trouble when building the necessary libraries. So for anyone else I recommend grabbing the Thrift source from their Git server or whatever and build the libraries that way. It's more work but it was only way I could use Thrift with MSVS.

Answer (score 0):

You need use VS2012 and boost_155 like minimum to create the thrift lib files.